# How do I change the alpha-style citation callout string?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am new to this forum and I looked, searched all articles that I think may have similar topics. But my question is still open. Maybe it's because my LaTeX skills are not the best.

Topic:

I am writing a thesis, and my institute tells me how to do formatting for citations (usually we have to use MS Word, so I'm glad I got the allowance to write in LaTeX).
But if we write something it should look like that:

LaTeX:

```
Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text. [EINS43]
```

BibTeX/Biber:

```
Author={Einstein},
Year={1943},
```

---

Usually if i compile my file it looks like:

```
Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text. [Ein43]
```

---

How can I change the content of the brackets?

Before I close this question I have to add some more. I also use norms like DIN or ISO. These have to appear like:

```
Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text. [ISO03]
```

To sum up everything i need:
Change the content of the bracket (I user *Biber* for my literature) from 3 letters to 4 uppercase letters; but when I have a norm it shall appear as 3 uppercase letters.
In my bib I also user the keys as I like them to appear. Maybe there is a possibility to change the cite-keys in the document just to the input keys?

Thank you for your help!

---

### This is my MWE:

Latex:

```
\documentclass[listof=totocnumbered, listof=nochaptergap, bibliography=totocnumbered, parskip, captions=nooneline, fontsize=11pt, twoside=semi, numbers=noenddot, open=right, draft=false, a4paper, footinclude=false, fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, isbn=false, url=false, firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\zitat}[2][]{\nopagebreak\nolinebreak\mbox{\cite[][#1]{#2}}} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------
% Also I found that (but I think thats from the template to change the appearance of the Bibliography, and has nothing to do with cite-keys):

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\upshape}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%  
   \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
    \intitlepunct}}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}
     \clearname{editor}% 
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}
}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    editor = {(Hrsg.).},
    editors = {(Hrsg.).},
    byeditor = {(Hrsg.).},
    editor = {(Hrsg.).}}    
%----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \zitat[S. 165-166]{ROOS15}\\
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\zitat{ZENK10}\\
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\zitat{DIN05}\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Biber (MWE.bib):

```
@conference{DIN05,
    Author = {{Normenausschuss Materialpr{\"u}fung im DIN}},
    Booktitle = {Norm DIN EN ISO 6507 Teil 1},
    Date-Added = {2015-07-01 16:33:02 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-07-03 03:23:48 +0000},
    Keywords = {DIN, Vickers, H{\"a}rtepr{\"u}fung},
    Title = {Metallische Werkstoffe - H{\"a}rtepr{\"u}fung nach Vickers - Teil 1: Pr{\"u}fverfahren},
    Year = {2005}}

@book{ZENK10,
    Address = {Germany},
    Author = {Zenker, R.; Buchwalder, A.},
    Date-Added = {2015-05-29 21:10:31 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-06-21 04:52:47 +0000},
    Keywords = {EBH, Pro-beam},
    Publisher = {pro-beam AG \& Co. KGaA},
    Subtitle = {Innovative Technologien f{\"u}r h{\"o}chste industrielle Anspr{\"u}che},
    Title = {Elektronenstrahlrandschichtbehandlung},
    Year = {2010}}

@book{ROOS15,
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Annote = {S. 179
6.4.2.9 Randschichth{\"a}rten},
    Author = {Roos, E.; Maile, K.},
    Date-Added = {2015-05-13 19:05:21 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-06-21 21:35:57 +0000},
    Isbn = {978-3-642-54989-2},
    Publisher = {Springer Vieweg},
    Subtitle = {Grundlagen, Anwendung, Pr{\"u}fung},
    Title = {Werkstoffkunde f{\"u}r Ingenieure},
    Year = {2015}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In the BibTeX format names are separated with `and` not with a semicolon, so you will want your author fields to read `Author = {Zenker, R.  and Buchwalder, A.},` and `Author = {Roos, E. and Maile, K.},`. `Address = {Germany}` seems pretty nondescript to me, either use something like `address = {Karlsruhe}` or drop it entirely.

Comment: I think your request quite unusual. Letting `biblatex` handle the labelling automatically will make sure there are no inconsistencies and you will have to think less. In some cases it might be useful to override a label created by `biblatex` in which case you can use the `shorthand` field (the `label` field is a fallback).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you want to use your entry names as labels.

To do that, simply add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{%
  \labelelement{%
    \field{citekey}
  }
}
```

In this way you are declaring that the label generated for your entries is the same as your entry name (pseudo-field `citekey`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[listof=totocnumbered, listof=nochaptergap, bibliography=totocnumbered, parskip, captions=nooneline, fontsize=11pt, twoside=semi, numbers=noenddot, open=right, draft=false, a4paper, footinclude=false, fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, isbn=false, url=false, firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\zitat}[2][]{\nopagebreak\nolinebreak\mbox{\cite[][#1]{#2}}}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{%
  \labelelement{%
    \field{citekey}
  }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
% Also I found that (but I think thats from the template to change the appearance of the Bibliography, and has nothing to do with cite-keys):

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\upshape}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
   \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
    \intitlepunct}}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}
}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    editor = {(Hrsg.).},
    editors = {(Hrsg.).},
    byeditor = {(Hrsg.).},
    editor = {(Hrsg.).}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \zitat[S. 165-166]{ROOS15}\\
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\zitat{ZENK10}\\
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\zitat{DIN05}\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As a side note, if your files are utf8-encoded, adding the line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your `.tex` document, you will be able to substitute things like `{\"o}` with simply `ö` both in your `.tex` and `.bib` files.

Comment: You might also want to add that the request with four letters and two digits of the year is possible with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4, strside=left, uppercase, names=1]{labelname}
    }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2, strside=right]{year}
    }
}` the norms will need a `shorthand` then, though.

Comment: @moewe Since the OP has requested two different `strwidth`s, that's why I didn't add this possibility `;-)`